# How to delete default SVG-paths in QGIS

Tags: qgis-3, svg

Under **"Settings -> Options -> System"** the SVG-paths are set. There are two default svg-paths:

```
C:/PROGRA-1/QGIS3/apps/qgis-Itr/./svg/
```

and

```
C:/Users/jan/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/svg/
```

I would like to permanently remove both paths.

I can remove them by clicking on the **"-"** symbol but when I restart QGIS, both of them reappear. Is there a way to remove both paths permanently?

Comment: That path is established when QGIS is opened, I think you can't eliminate it completely  https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/736e8cbbc34ef8ea4ec935851766dd295a365b1a/src/core/qgsapplication.cpp#L271

Answer (score 1):

As [@FranRaga](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/49538/fran-raga) mentioned, the default paths are recreated each time QGIS is loaded. An alternative could be to create a **startup script** which removes the SVG paths when QGIS is loaded.

You can create such a script in `C:/Users/jan/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3/startup.py` with the following code:

```
from qgis.core import QgsApplication
QgsApplication.setDefaultSvgPaths([''])
```